# PROBLEMA CON COMPONENTES EN REACT NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native

Esta es la primera pregunta que hago en stack overflow, el caso es que me estoy peleando con react native porque al poner algun componente como button no me carga la app. El código que tengo es este:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  Button
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

const App: () => React$Node = () => { //Esta línea venia ya en app.js
  return (
    <>
      <View>
        <Button></Button>
      </View>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

mira que el componente Button debes usarlo así como dice la documentación [Button](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button) :

```
<Button
  title="Press me"
  onPress={() => {}}
/>
```

Otra cosa estos: `<> </>` te estan sobrando en tu codigo.

Answer (score 0):

ya he solucionado el problema, había que introducir un elemento, por ejemplo text dentro del button, tal que así:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  Button
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <View>
        <Button>
          <Text>Texto del boton</Text>
        </Button>
      </View>
    </>
  );
};
```